# Unload a video from memory, but not delete it from page

Tags: javascript, html, video, memory, electron

I'm making a game with Electron that allows access to many videos on a single page. Electron is eating up endless memory by constantly readding videos to the memory when they are played after being paused. This leads to a single 6mb video taking up several hundred mbs of memory at some points in the game. Garbage collection does eventually kick in, but the responsiveness of the videos suffer when the application is reaching the memory limit.

The game is linear, so I am using `video.pause();video.src ="";video.load();` to manually remove the videos from the page at certain parts of the game. This works, but it is not ideal for all users.  I would like to unload the videos from the ram whenever they are paused, but not remove them from the page, allowing them to be reloaded again and played when called upon.

Currently I am placing the video in HTML like this:

```
    <video id="video1" width="100%"  preload="none" loop muted >
    <source src="video1.webm" type="video/webm">              
  </video>
```

It is being played like this:

```
   function playvideo1(){
   var video = document.getElementById("video1");           
   var isPlaying = video.currentTime > 0 && !video.paused && !video.ended && 
   video.readyState > 2;
   if (!isPlaying) {video.currentTime = 0;video.play();}}
```

And paused like this:

```
function video1(){
   var video = document.getElementById("video1");
   var isPlaying = video.currentTime > 0;
   if (isPlaying) {video.pause();}}
```

I've searched and searched but I haven't found anyway to unload the video without removing its source. How could I unload a video from the memory without deleting it from the page?

Comment: pausing the video does not free up that memory the video is pointing to, you have to unload the video from the DOM in other to free up that memory

Comment: @0.sh Is it possible then to delete the video from DOM and then have it created new everytime it is called upon?